# How does calculating relevance scoring in Elasticsearch differ from Couchbase?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, couchbase, tf-idf, relevance

I wonder whether relevance score in elasticsearch has differences with couchbase or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this 2019](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/full-text-search-relevance-scores-in-multi-tenants-environment/21688/4) couchbase thread, it looks like they are still using the [tf/idf](http://www.tfidf.com/) for scoring, while Elasticsearch used to have the same algorithm but now moved to [BM25 algorithm for score calculation from 5.0](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-1-how-shards-affect-relevance-scoring-in-elasticsearch).

Note: TF/IDF is a very popular algorism for calculating the relevance score and based on term frequency and inverse document frequency, while BM25 is the latest and **improvised form based on probabilistic** scoring more details about them can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2016/sf/improved-text-scoring-with-bm25) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2016/sf/improved-text-scoring-with-bm25).

Note: As in the question, it's not mentioned for what purpose you are comparing both the relevance of the system, My two cents are if you are building a full-blown search system and relevance matters for you, then you should choose Elasticseaech whose primary function is to search and has a lot of flexibility in choosing different algorithm and different ways to define the scoring mechanism, which is not present in NoSQL solution like Couchbase.